# JSP modularization

Tags: java, jsp, web

Consdier the below HTML fragment

```
<ol>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>
    <ol>
      <li>Item 3 1</li>
      <li>Item 3 2</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
```

I want to move the inner list code to a separate section - something like function call - to have better view of single level of abstraction. Something like below:

```
<ol>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li><div class="gragment" id="fragment1"/></li>
</ol>

<div id="gragment1">
    <ol>
      <li>Item 3 1</li>
      <li>Item 3 2</li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

Is there framework or tool to achieve this in JSP?

Regards,
Rejeev.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch For jsp:includee the HTML fragment needs to be in a separate file, which I don't want. I want the fragment to be in the same JSP file (may be at the end). Something similar to private functions in a Java Class.

Comment: Like a [declaration](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnaos.html)?

Comment: Have you used `FTL` ? `FreeMarkerTemplate`. In that macro provide facility you are looking for.

Comment: Use custom tags http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnalj.html

Comment: @DanglingPiyush Custom Tags content needs to be in a separate file. I want the content of the subsection in the same JSP file. Is it possible to specify the custom tag in the same JSP itself?